# Убрать из датафрейма строки по времени

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

В [датафрейме](https://we.tl/t-9j8y5AUcQ1) нужно оставить только те строки, в которых df.Time_1 больше предыдущего df.Time_2 и df.Time_1. Например - вторая строка выкидывается, потому что 2/1/2022 22:49:00 меньше чем 23:50:00 в Time_2 предыдущей строки.

```
df = 

Date_start  Time_1      Date_end    Time_2      trig
2/1/2022    21:56:00    2/1/2022    23:50:00    0
2/1/2022    22:49:00    2/1/2022    2:17:00     0
2/2/2022    23:34:00    2/2/2022    2:22:00     2
2/3/2022    1:49:00     2/3/2022    2:13:00     1
2/3/2022    1:54:00     2/3/2022    3:54:00     1
2/3/2022    3:19:00     2/3/2022    3:54:00     2
2/4/2022    0:29:00     2/4/2022    3:29:00     2
2/4/2022    22:17:00    2/4/2022    23:41:00    0
2/4/2022    22:28:00    2/4/2022    22:32:00    0
2/4/2022    22:49:00    2/4/2022    1:16:00     1
```

Результат который должен получиться:

```
Date_start  Time_1      Date_end    Time_2      trig
2/1/2022    21:56:00    2/1/2022    23:50:00    0
2/2/2022    23:34:00    2/2/2022    2:22:00     2
2/3/2022    1:49:00     2/3/2022    2:13:00     1
2/3/2022    3:19:00     2/3/2022    3:54:00     2
2/4/2022    0:29:00     2/4/2022    3:29:00     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм довольно простой (у вас избыточное условие - сравнивать нужно Datetime начала только с Datetime конца предыдущей строки, потому что Datetime конца всегда больше своего Datetime начала):

1. получаем колонки с типом данных datetime из исходных
2. сдвигаем колонку с временем окончания на 1, чтобы сделать векторное сравнение, при этом заполняем первую позицию вместо pd.NaT минимальным значением минус 1 минута чтобы не выпадала первая строка
3. теперь выделяем только те строки, которые соответствуют условию  удаляем ненужные колонки и сбрасываем индекс:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df["datetime1"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start'] + ' ' + df['Time_1'], dayfirst=True)
df["datetime2"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end'] + ' ' + df['Time_2'], dayfirst=True)

df["datetime2"] = df["datetime2"].shift().fillna(df["datetime1"].min()-timedelta(minutes=1))
df = df[df["datetime1"]>df["datetime2"]].drop(columns=["datetime1", "datetime2"]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

теперь df:

```
  Date_start    Time_1  Date_end    Time_2  trig
0   2/1/2022  21:56:00  2/1/2022  23:50:00     0
1   2/2/2022  23:34:00  2/2/2022   2:22:00     2
2   2/3/2022   1:49:00  2/3/2022   2:13:00     1
3   2/4/2022   0:29:00  2/4/2022   3:29:00     2
4   2/4/2022  22:17:00  2/4/2022  23:41:00     0
5   2/4/2022  22:49:00  2/4/2022   1:16:00     1
```

проверьте свои расчеты - мой результат не полностью совпадает с вашим.

Comment: @ssoop А вы проверьте условия. Это у вас пример вывода неправильный. Либо исходные данные )

Comment: Исправил - одна строка была лишняя, да. В любом случае после применения кода выше остается лишние 2 строки 4-го числа

Comment: @ssoop Так они остаются ровно по вашему условию: `22:17:00` > `0:29:00` и > `3:29:00`; `22:49:00` > `22:28:00` и > `22:32:00`, что не так то? )

Answer (score 1):

Проверил на ваших данных. Судя по всему, вы имели в виду всё же сочетание даты и времени, а не просто время. Поэтому нужно добавить преобразование столбцов в полную дату-время, спасибо **strawdog**:

```
df["DateTime_1"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_start'] + ' ' + df['Time_1'], dayfirst=True)
df["DateTime_2"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_end'] + ' ' + df['Time_2'], dayfirst=True)

df.loc[(df.shift().DateTime_1.isna()) |\
       ((df.DateTime_1 > df.shift().DateTime_1) &\
        (df.DateTime_1 > df.shift().DateTime_2))]
```

- преобразуем строковые части даты-времени в в тип `datetime`
- первую строку не с чем сравнивать, поэтому её проверяем по условию `isna` в сдвинутом датасете
- комбинируем буквально те условия, которые вы задали

Вывод:

```
    Date_start  Time_1      Date_end    Time_2     trig DateTime_1 DateTime_2
0   2/1/2022    21:56:00    2/1/2022    23:50:00    0   2022-01-02 21:56:00 2022-01-02 23:50:00
2   2/2/2022    23:34:00    2/2/2022    2:22:00     2   2022-02-02 23:34:00 2022-02-02 02:22:00
3   2/3/2022    1:49:00     2/3/2022    2:13:00     1   2022-03-02 01:49:00 2022-03-02 02:13:00
6   2/4/2022    0:29:00     2/4/2022    3:29:00     2   2022-04-02 00:29:00 2022-04-02 03:29:00
7   2/4/2022    22:17:00    2/4/2022    23:41:00    0   2022-04-02 22:17:00 2022-04-02 23:41:00
9   2/4/2022    22:49:00    2/4/2022    1:16:00     1   2022-04-02 22:49:00 2022-04-02 01:16:00
```

При этом `3:19:00` не больше ведь, чем `3:54:00`, а `22:49:00` наоборот - явно больше, чем время 1 и 2 в предыдущей строке, поэтому у вас неправильно что-то или алгоритм, или пример вывода, который должен получиться.

Comment: напоминаю: `.shift()` == `.shift(1)` - смещение вперед на одну строку - на следующую. `.shift(-1)` -  смещение назад на одну строку :)

Comment: @ssoop, код делает буквально то, что вы указали в своем вопросе (_оставить только те строки, в которых df.Time_1 больше предыдущего df.Time_2 и df.Time_1_).  То есть какое условие вы указали, такой результат и получаете.

Comment: @ssoop Ну я писал без компа в тот момент и буквально забил ваше условие. Всё же нужно сравнивать datetime, судя по всему, а не просто время, как вы написали )