# Преобразовать столбец времени датафрейм

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

В датафрейме время записано в столбце Time как 235500 или 101400 или 82300. Пробую к этим минуткам добавить столбец с интервалами к какому часу они принадлежат через `df['hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Time']).hour` но не получается (пишутся везде нули), видимо нужно преобразовать столбец с временем.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваши проблемы начинаются с того, как вы [**читаете** данные из CSV файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1379368/211923). В ответах на тот ваш вопрос вам уже посоветовали создать столбец типа `datetime64`, у которого есть очень много удобных методов и атрибутов для работы с датой и временем.

Если бы у вас был столбец типа `datetime64` вы бы просто могли воспользоваться атрибутом [df["<col_name>"].dt.hour](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
datetime_series = pd.Series(
    pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=3, freq="h")
)
datetime_series
0   2000-01-01 00:00:00
1   2000-01-01 01:00:00
2   2000-01-01 02:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
datetime_series.dt.hour
0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64
```

---

В качестве "костыльного" решения могу предложить решение с целочисленным делением:

```
In [11]: df["hr"] = df["time"] // 10000

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
     time  hr
0  235500  23
1  101400  10
2   82300   8
```

Но правильнее все-таки использовать правильный тип данных - `datetime64`.

Comment: костыльный режим хорош

Comment: @ssoop, что-то мне подсказывает, что это не последний ваш вопрос о том как работать со временем/датой в неправильном формате. Избавиться от этих проблем вы сможете сразу и навсегда после того как создадите столбец с типом данных `datetime64` ;)

Comment: MaxU, а можете подсказать как сделать тоже самое для 15 минут? df["hr"] = df["time"] // 10000
- на сколько надо делить?

Comment: @ssoop, а что значит "сделать тоже самое для 15 минут" в контексте времени? Что должно получиться из `235500`?

Answer (score 1):

Если Ваши значения - минуты и Вам из них нужно получить часы, то возможен такой вариант.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [235500, 101400, 82300]})
df['hours_time'] = df.time.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='m').hour)
print(df)

>>>
     time  hours_time
0  235500          13
1  101400          10
2   82300           3
```

Comment: я думаю `235500` - это `23:55:00`, а не число минут прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` ;)

Comment: а зачем тогда - "к этим минуткам...." ?)

Comment: скорее всего автор вопроса любит трудности и поэтому не хочет работать с датой/временем в соответствующем формате ;)